# AutoMapper throws exception when projecting to nullable enum

Tags: c#, linq, exception, automapper

In my project I have a Linq queryable (actually an EF6 collection) that I need to convert to a collection of data transfer objects.  I'm using `AutoMapper` throughout the project, especially for its ability to do type projection thereby reducing the amount of SQL generated by the Linq query.

But I've got a small problem with one of my DTO classes. The associated database column contains a nullable string, which I wish to map to a nullable enum.  But at runtime an exception is thrown

> No coercion operator is defined between types 'System.String' and 'System.Nullable`1[AutomapperEnumTest.Method]'.

Here's a complete test program that demonstrates the problem: (see [.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8EfHPq))

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using AutoMapper;
using AutoMapper.QueryableExtensions;

namespace AutomapperEnumTest
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Configure();
            var src = new SourceType[] { new SourceType { Name = "Rob", MethodName = "AUTO" } };
            var results = src.AsQueryable()
                        .ProjectTo<DestType>();

            foreach(var item in results)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("DestType Name={0} Method={1}", item.Name, item.Method));
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Done");
        }

        private static void Configure()
        {
            Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.CreateMap<string, Method?>().ProjectUsing(src => src == "MANUAL" ? Method.MANUAL : Method.AUTO);
                cfg.CreateMap<SourceType, DestType>()
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.Method, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.MethodName));
            });
        }
    }

    public enum Method
    {
        MANUAL=0,
        AUTO=1
    }

    public class DestType
    {
        public string Name {get; set; }
        public Method? Method {get; set; }
    }

    public class SourceType
    {
        public string Name {get; set; }
        public string MethodName {get; set; }
    }
}
```

Now if I change the property from `Method?` to `Method` it works fine (see this modification in [.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/urx9jy)).  But I don't want to do this, so my question is how do I inform Linq/AutoMapper that it should use my `ProjectUsing` for the nullable enum?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same happens in the latest AutoMapper v5.2.0.

After looking at the source code, I think it is a bug inside the `ExpressionBuilder` class because for some unknown reason `NullableExpressionBinder` is given higher priority than `CustomProjectionExpressionBinder` (and others), so basically when you map non nullable type to nullable, all the custom mappings are ignored.

I would suggest you to report it on their repository. Until then, I could suggest you the following workaround (hack). Include the following custom class in your project:

```
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;
using AutoMapper;
using AutoMapper.QueryableExtensions;
using AutoMapper.QueryableExtensions.Impl;

class NullableExpressionBinderEx : IExpressionBinder
{
    public static void Install()
    {
        var bindersField = typeof(ExpressionBuilder).GetField("Binders", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
        var binders = (IExpressionBinder[])bindersField.GetValue(null);
        binders[0] = new NullableExpressionBinderEx();
    }
    IExpressionBinder baseBinder = new NullableExpressionBinder();
    private NullableExpressionBinderEx() { }
    public bool IsMatch(PropertyMap propertyMap, TypeMap propertyTypeMap, ExpressionResolutionResult result)
    {
        if (propertyTypeMap != null && propertyTypeMap.CustomProjection != null)
            return false;
        return baseBinder.IsMatch(propertyMap, propertyTypeMap, result);
    }
    public MemberAssignment Build(IConfigurationProvider configuration, PropertyMap propertyMap, TypeMap propertyTypeMap, ExpressionRequest request, ExpressionResolutionResult result, IDictionary<ExpressionRequest, int> typePairCount)
    {
        return baseBinder.Build(configuration, propertyMap, propertyTypeMap, request, result, typePairCount);
    }
}
```

then add the following line to your `Configure` method:

```
NullableExpressionBinderEx.Install();
```

and the issue should be solved.

Comment: Thanks for providing such a complete answer. I've tested it and this does solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could map MethodName to Method manually, unless I'm missing something in your question.

```
private static void Configure()
{
    Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.CreateMap<SourceType, DestType>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Method, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => 
                src.MethodName == "MANUAL" ? Method.MANUAL : Method.AUTO));
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Win, your solution does work in this simple example.  I didn't think to try that because in the actual application the enum is used in multiple places so I would prefer the type to have its own mapping configuration (e.g. a  `ProjectUsing` configuration) .  Do you know if this is possible and, if not, what is getting in the way?

Comment: in my second .Net Fiddle example you will see that there is a global mapping from `String` to the `Method` enum.  This works fine, but the same technique does not seem to work for `System.Nullable<Method>`.

Comment: It is something wrong in ***ProjectTo*** extension method  `src.AsQueryable().ProjectTo<DestType>()`. Your code works with `var results = src.Select(Mapper.Map<SourceType, DestType>);`